# I am trying to read a txt file into an array but get an OutOfBoundsException(0)

Tags: java, arrays, indexoutofboundsexception, filereader, bluej

```
public static double [] loadGravityData( ) throws IOException
{
  File fileName = new File("gravity1.txt");
  Scanner inFile = new Scanner(fileName);

  double [] gravityData = {};
  while(inFile.hasNext())
   {    

   for(int i = 0; i <= gravityData.length; i++)
    {
     gravityData[i] = inFile.nextDouble();

    }

   }  
   inFile.close();

return gravityData;
}
```

The gravityData of i part is what is returning the exception. Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Declare array in Java?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1200621/declare-array-in-java)

Comment: by doing  `double [] gravityData = {};` you have a zero-length array

Answer (score 1):

You should initialize the array to be as long as the amounts of items you wish to read, and change

```
for(int i = 0; i <= gravityData.length; i++)
...
```

to

```
for(int i = 0; i < gravityData.length; i++)
...
```

This is because an array of length **n** has elements at **0,1,...,n-1**.

If you count them you can tell that there are in fact n elements.

**Edit**, thanks Trengot

If you don't know how many items there are to read in advance, I suggest you look at [ArrayList](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html), which is a generic dynamic array type

Comment: Unless you're using concurrency, a `List` such as `ArrayList` would be better than `Vector`.

Comment: @Trengot You're right, I haven't programmed Java in a while and got used to vectors of C++. Edited!

Comment: I changed the <= to < and i get the same thing

Comment: Did you change the rest as well? (Allocate the array or alternatively use an ArrayList?)

Answer (score 0):

where are you allocating the array?
In Java, arrays are of a fixed length and they do not auto-expand. In your case, you should use an ArrayList instead.

Additionally, you should change the <= to <

Comment: The additionally part of this is the cause of the error. The rest should be the aside.